# R return corrplot as object

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot, grob

`corrplot` plots a correlation matrix, but it does not return a graphical object (grob)

I would like to plot several correlation matrices on a single page. For normal plots, I would use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package. However since corrplot only prints and does not return an object, I can't see how to do this.

Is there a workaround or a better alternative to `corrplot` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the old standby `par(mfrow=c(x, y))` where `x` is the number of rows you wish to plot and `y` the numberof columns. It then posts across and then down as you call the plots.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
corrplot(cor(mat1))
corrplot(cor(mat2))
corrplot(cor(mat3))
corrplot(cor(mat4))

par(mfrow = c(1, 1)) #To clear layout
```

Will plot as

```
Mat1 | Mat2
-----------
Mat3 | Mat4
```

Answer (score 11):

The recent `gridGraphics` package could probably do what you asked: return the plot as a grob.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(mat))

library(gridGraphics)
grab_grob <- function(){
  grid.echo()
  grid.grab()
}

g <- grab_grob()
library(gridExtra)
grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(g,g,g,g)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got your question right, but maybe what you are looking for is simple `layout` ?

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)

layout(matrix(1:2))
corrplot(cor(mat))
corrplot(cor(mat))
```