# Plotrix in Grid Extra: "no grobs' allowed in "gList"

Tags: r, gridextra, plotrix

I created a battleship plot using Plotrix:

```
k<-battleship.plot(data, main="Distribution",xlab="Type",ylab="Phase", 
                                                        maxxspan=0.6,maxyspan=0.45)

j<-battleship.plot(data2, main="Distribution",xlab="Type",ylab="Phase", 
                                                        maxxspan=0.6,maxyspan=0.45)
```

I want to print both plots together using gridExtra:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(j, k, ncol=1, nrow =2, top=("Types by Phase"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in gList(list(mar = c(2, 5, 5, 1), wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

I have tried arrangeGrob without success.

How can overcome this problem?
ggplot2 plots are working great, even with the same data.

Comment: `battleship.plot` is not a grid plot - it is base R. So arrange with `par(mfrow(...))`

Comment: However, if you are wanting to arrange, say plots using ggplot, and these, you can convert the plot to a grob using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929452/r-return-corrplot-as-object/27948707#27948707

Comment: look at `j` and `k`: they're not grobs but lists of parameters (`mar`) for base graphics