# grid.arrange with filled.contour in R Studio

Tags: r

I created a few plots with the filled.contour function. Then I would like to plot two of the plots next to each other. Therefore I used the grid.arrange function.
This is my code:

```
install.packages("gridExtra")
install.packages("lattice")
install.packages("grid")
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Fake data 
x <- c(1:10)

y <- c(1:10)
z<-matrix(data=c(1:100), nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow = FALSE)


p1<-filled.contour(x,y,z, color = terrain.colors, asp = 1) # simple


# Lay out both plots
grid.arrange(p1,p1, ncol=2)
```

But what I get is:

> Error in gList(list(wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height
>   = 1,  :    only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

Thats why I tried this:

```
install.packages("gridExtra")
install.packages("lattice")
install.packages("grid")
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Fake data (taken from the fill.contour help examples)
x <- c(1:10)

y <- c(1:10)
z<-matrix(data=c(1:100), nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow = FALSE)


p1<-filled.contour(x,y,z, color = terrain.colors, asp = 1) # simple
p1<-grob(p1)
is.grob(p1)


# Lay out both plots
grid.arrange(p1,p1, ncol=2)
```

But this does not work either. Can you help me please?

Comment: `filled.contour` is a base graphics function, rather than a `lattice` function, and does not produce a grob or an object that can be turned into a grob (though maybe it's possible to turn it into a grob using functions in the `gridBase` package). If you type `p1<-filled.contour(x,y,z, color = terrain.colors, asp = 1)` and then type `p1` the output is `NULL`. `lattice` has the `contour`, `contourplot` and `levelplot` functions that might be what you need.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929452/r-return-corrplot-as-object./#27948707

Comment: My problem with contourplot and levelplot ist the fact, that they require different input than filled.contour.

Answer (score 1):

As @eipi10 pointed out, filled.contour is base graphics, so you should use base arrangement functions, i.e. `par(mfrow = c(1,2))` to arrange two plots side by side.

EDIT: apparently filled contour is famous for defeating all layout attempts. I tried `par(plt...)` `layout()` and `par(mfrow...)`  I found filled.countour3 as a workaround as described here:

http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/sites/qerm/images/e/ec/Example_4_panel_contour_plot_with_one_legend.R

and in question 14758391 on this site.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I tried that. You receive two seperate plots, not one plot  with both.

Comment: Ok. Can you modify my code in order to make it work or can you give me another example code? I would really appriciate that.

Comment: @rsl93; my apologies, you cant use `mfrow` in this case as the function `filled.contour` has repeated `plot.new()` calls through it. Id suggest using the approach from the link i give above (ps if you looked at `p1` object in your code it is null, hence why you can't combine them: generally you cannot assign a base R plot to an object)