# Plotting tanglegrams subplots in R using dendextend

Tags: r, plot, visualization, dendrogram, dendextend

I am plotting Tanglegrams in R using [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html). I am wondering if it is possible to plot multiple subplots using `par(mfrow = c(2,2))`?

I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

```
library(dendextend)
dend15 <- c(1:5) %>% dist %>% hclust(method = "average") %>% as.dendrogram
dend15 <- dend15 %>% set("labels_to_char")
dend51 <- dend15 %>% set("labels", as.character(5:1)) %>% match_order_by_labels(dend15)
dends_15_51 <- dendlist(dend15, dend51)

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
tanglegram(dends_15_51)
tanglegram(dends_15_51)
tanglegram(dends_15_51)
tanglegram(dends_15_51)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It is not possible to use `par(mfrow=...)` with the function `tanglegram`, but it is possible using `layout`.

**Explanation:** If you look closer at function `tanglegram`, you'll see (`methods(tanglegram)`) that, underneath, there are several methods, among which, `dendextend:::tanglegram.dendrogram` which is called to draw the tanglegram (as can be seen inside `dendextend:::tanglegram.dendlist` function).

Inside this function, there is a call to `layout`:

```
layout(matrix(1:3, nrow = 1), widths = columns_width)
```

This "erases" your previous setting of `par(mfrow=c(2, 2))` and changes it to `c(1, 3)` (just for the "time" of the function though because at the end of the function, the value is reset...).

Indeed, in the help page of `layout`, it says:

> These functions are totally incompatible with the other mechanisms for arranging plots on a device: par(mfrow), par(mfcol) and split.screen.

**Conclusion:** If you want to plot several tanglegrams in the same "window" you'll need to use the `layout` call (with 12 subparts: 2 rows and 6 columns) ahead of the calls to `tanglegram` and suppress the `layout` call inside `tanglegram` using the argument `just_one=FALSE`.

***Example of drawing several tanglegrams:***

Using the code below, you can then obtain the desired plot (I put the function's default widths for the layout):

```
layout(matrix(1:12, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), widths=rep(c(5, 3, 5), 2))
tanglegram.dendlist_mod(dends_15_51, just_one=FALSE)
tanglegram.dendlist_mod(dends_15_51, just_one=FALSE)
tanglegram.dendlist_mod(dends_15_51, just_one=FALSE)
tanglegram.dendlist_mod(dends_15_51, just_one=FALSE)
```

[image]

This was done by updating the dendextend package in which: I modified the 2 functions `tanglegram.dendrogram` and `tanglegram.dendlist` to add a `just_one` parameter, which defaults to `TRUE` and changed the line of the `layout` in `tanglegram.dendrogram` to:

```
 if (just_one) layout(matrix(1:3, nrow = 1), widths = columns_width)
```

I also suppressed the reset of `par` parameters and of course changed the call in `tanglegram.dendlist` (now called `tanglegram.dendlist_mod`) so it calls the new modified function, incorporates the `just_one` parameter and passes it to the modified `tanglegram.dendrogram` function.

Comment: as a quick alternative you could grab the image, and convert it to a grid object and then combine.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929452/r-return-corrplot-as-object/#27948707

Comment: @user20650 I thought of using `grid` but wasn't aware that one can grab an image. I've been missing this package, thanks!

Comment: @user20650 good idea, but the solution you link to doesn't work with tanglegram, unfortunately. Problem seems to be that `grid.echo` chokes on horizontal dendrograms (e.g. `plot(dend51); grid.echo()` works, `plot(dend51, horiz = TRUE); grid.echo()` throws an error) and this is required to convert the image to a grid object.

Comment: @HeatherTurner; I really should try things first!! Interesting how it fails on horiz (and then also margin_outer).

Comment: I think problem comes from the fact that, at one moment, the min of x-axis is above the max. Modifying the computation of `ticksub` inside `C_axis` (which is called and inside which is th call to `unit` that throws the error) avoids the error. But again, at least one function has to be modified...

Comment: Shame grid approach didn't work here - in that case modifying `tangle.dendrogram` is probably simpler. Note as alternative to creating `_mod` functions, you could use `fixInNamespace(tangle.dendrogram, "dendextend")` to make the changes, then you could use `tanglegram` with the new `just_one` argument directly.

Comment: HI @Cath do you want to make a pull request for this addition? https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend

Answer (score 4):

Rather than creating a combined plot in a single graphical device, you could create multiple plots and arrange them when you put them in a document. The `knitr` package makes it easy to do this, by using `fig.show = "hold"` to hold on to multiple plots produced in a single R chunk and specifying a relevant `out.width`, e.g. 50% to have two plots in a row, for when the plots are placed in the document.

For example, in an R markdown (`.Rmd`) file you might have

````
```{r, fig.show = "hold", out.width = "50%", echo = FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dendextend))
dend15 <- c(1:5) %>% dist %>% hclust(method = "average") %>% as.dendrogram
dend15 <- dend15 %>% set("labels_to_char")
dend51 <- dend15 %>% set("labels", as.character(5:1)) %>% match_order_by_labels(dend15)
dends_15_51 <- dendlist(dend15, dend51)
tanglegram(dends_15_51, margin_outer = 1)
plot.new()
tanglegram(dends_15_51, margin_outer = 1)
plot.new()
tanglegram(dends_15_51, margin_outer = 1)
plot.new()
tanglegram(dends_15_51, margin_outer = 1)
```
````

which when `knit`ted to HTML, would look like the following:

[image]

There a few modifications I made to the code:

- Suppressed package startup messages from `dendextend`.
- Increased default `margin_outer` to avoid overlapping x axis labels from neighbouring plots.
- Added `plot.new()` in between calls to `tanglegram`, otherwise the next plot would be drawn on top of the previous one (this is a result of `tanglegram` using `layout` and is not needed in general when producing multiple plots).

The same approach can be used in `.Rnw` files. If you are compiling to PDF (via LaTeX) you can add a figure caption and subcaptions, see [`knitr` demo #067 - Graphics Options](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/067-graphics-options.Rnw) for more detail.